# Changing Constraints of UITableViewCell, not affecting TableViewCell height in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am changing the constraint for Cell, But the height of the Cell remains same till deque, after dequeuing it gives correct result.

Any idea how can we reload the cell if the cell constraints are manipulated?

Using Rxswift for Cell View Model, but TableView is in Objc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is always nice to share your code.

How are you changing the height of your cell? Are you using the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate.

For changes to appear, I use this code.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

If this does not work for you, please share your code and I would update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah i know this update methods but, I am not using heightForRowAtIndex delegate. And i am using Rx for manipulating Cell constraints.